# Chnage prefix name of Hole_ID for multiple rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-update

I have 200 records with HoleID name starting with MGGC0001 to MGGC0200. But I want to change MGGC with MEGC for all the records in sql database. Would you please let me the know the query I can use to update all HoleID's with MEGC prefix.

Thanks!

Regards,
Dinesh

Comment: 1. Tag the DBMS your are using. 2. Include sample data and desired output as `formatted text`. 3. Show your attempt so far. (see: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Hi I am using SQL Server Database

Answer (score 1):

Simply use `REPLACE`

```
SELECT REPLACE(HOLELID, 'MGGC', 'MEGC')
FROM tbl;
```

But this does not change any of your existing data. 
If that is the case, then use:

```
UPDATE tbl 
SET HOLELID = REPLACE(HOLELID, 'MGGC', 'MEGC');
```

Comment: @DineshGuleria great! If you don't mind, please tag as accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

I strongly recommend an approach more like this:

```
update t
    set HoleId = stuff(HoleId, 1, 4, 'MEGC')
    where HoleId like 'MGGC%';
```

First, this only affects rows that start with 'MGGC' rather than all rows.  Second, this only replaces 'MGGC' at the beginning of the string rather than anywhere in the string.

Or for a `select`:

```
select (case when HoleId like 'MGGC%'
             then stuff(HoleId, 1, 4, 'MEGC')
             else HoleId
        end)
```